# How can I apply the subdivision without breaking the models weight deforms?

Tags: armature, subdivision-surface

I'm trying to apply the subdivision for a rigged and weighted model and I can't figure out how to do it without breaking the weight deforms, I'm trying to figure this out because I plan on exporting future animated character models to Unreal Engine with applied subdivisions and I don't want to have to apply the subdivision before the export as to keep the model generally lower poly when animating in Blender.
Is it even possible to apply the subdivision without having to redo the weights manually?[image: Example]
[image: Example2]

Comment: hello please share your file